# Derivative of the logarithm of a tensor

Tags: tensor-calculus, differentiation

Consider a generic tensor, for example a rank-2 tensor $R_{\mu \nu}$ (but we can take whatever object with indices). I can of course take the logarithm of it, $\log R_{\mu \nu}$.
However, what happens when we take the derivative of it, say with respect to some $\lambda$?
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{d\lambda}\log R_{\mu \nu}=\frac{1}{R_{\mu \nu}}\frac{d}{d\lambda}R_{\mu \nu}
\end{equation}
Somehow there is something wrong here. We started with a tensor with two indices (the left-hand side of the above equation) and after deriving we get a contraction of the indices (right-hand side).
So the equation above equates something with two indices with something without free indices, thus it cannot be correct, even though we are applying the usual rule of differentiation of the logarithm. 
What is going on here?

**EDIT (from comments):**

Ok, so we have a tensor, $R = R_{\mu \nu} \otimes dx^\mu \otimes dx^\nu$. I take the logarithm not of the tensor itself, but of the components $R_{\mu \nu}$ with respect to a certain basis. I take the logarithm of $R_{\mu \nu}$ as I would do in normal calculus, because the components are just normal functions. For example, let us assume that we are in 4 dimensions so that $\mu, \nu = 1,...,4$. Then let's say that $R_{11} = e$, $R_{22} = 3$. Then, $(\log R)_{11} = 1$, $(\log R)_{22} = \log 3$.

Comment: What do you mean by the logarithm of a rank-2 tensor?  Are you assuming that it's symmetric & positive definite?

Comment: I just assume that $R_{\mu \nu}$ is positive so that it makes sense to take the logarithm of it. I take the logarithm of it just like any normal function $f(x)$.

Comment: A contraction of repeated indices is rotationally invariant. Taking the log of a single component is not. Just write (no summation) beside the equation and then it will be correct.

Comment: I can't see how you might take the logarithm of a tensor. The components of a tensor depend on your coordinate system. How exactly are you defining $\log{R_{\mu\nu}}$?

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you mean here, I'm afraid.  Normally we can talk about a *matrix* logarithm $\ln A$ by defining it in terms of a power series in the matrix.  But that relies on being able to define $A^n$ for an arbitrary matrix.  You can't do this for $R_{\mu \nu}$ unless you change the index structure.

Comment: Ok, so we have a tensor, $R=R_{\mu \nu} \otimes dx^{\mu}\otimes dx^{\nu}$. I take the logarithm not of the tensor itself, but of the components $R_{\mu \nu}$ with respect to a certain basis.  I take the logarithm of $R_{\mu \nu}$ as I would do in normal calculus, because the components are just normal functions. For example, let us assume that we are in 4 dimensions so that $\mu, \nu=1,...,4$. Then let's say that $R_{11}=e$, $R_{22}=3$. Then, $\log R_{11} = 1$, $\log R_{22}=\log 3$

Comment: You're not getting clear answers because the logarithm of the components of a tensor is not a tensor. Your equation is correct, but without summing over the indices: it states the equality of the $\mu\nu$ componentes of two matrices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write "$\ln(R_{\mu\nu})$" you need to be clear on what you mean by it. An obvious interpretation is that you are taking the component-wise logarithm of the tensor. A less obvious interpretation would be to try to express it as a power series of powers of the tensor seen as a linear operator. One can [use the definition that $X$ is the logarithm](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10659-008-9169-x) if $e^X=R$ given some definition of powers, but this is multi-valued and runs into problems if any of the powers are singular.

In any case, some of these choices do not produce a tensor in the sense that it is invariant under coordinate transformations. Consider the transformation $R'_{\mu\nu}=\Lambda_{\mu i}\Lambda_{\nu j}R_{ij}$: for a component-wise logarithm $$\ln(R'_{\mu \nu})=\ln(\Lambda_{\mu i})+\ln(\Lambda_{\nu j})+\ln(R_{\mu \nu}):$$ it is not at all transforming as a tensor should! The derivative is hence also not a proper tensor.

[Jog actually derives a tensor logarithm](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10659-008-9169-x) based on the above exponential series expansion, a fairly complex expression of the log of a tensor $T$ in terms of nilpotent parts $N_i$ and projection vectors $P_i$ along the different eigenvalues of the tensor (with multiplicities $m_i$). I think this one is actually rotationally invariant.
$$\ln(T) = \sum_{i=1}^k \left[(\ln\lambda_i)P_i + \sum_{j=1}^{m_i-1} \frac{(-1)^{j-1} N_i^j}{j\lambda_i^j}\right]$$
where $T=\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i P_i+N_i$. This can then be used to construct a derivative, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial T} \ln T = \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i^{-1} P_i\otimes P_i^T + \sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1, j\neq i}^k \frac{\ln \lambda_i - \ln \lambda_j}{\lambda_i - \lambda_j}  P_i\otimes P_i^T$$
I note that this is the derivative of the tensor logarithm "along" the tensor, rather than along some random direction in the linear space. But it does show that one can make "proper" derivatives of tensor logarithms... under a host of assumptions of nonsingularity etc.

It is always important to consider what kind of object one is trying to operate on. Treating tensors (multilinear operators on vector spaces) as matrices (linear maps) or as arrays does not always produce the same result. Equally, you should consider what you want to use the operation for: it is entirely possible to produce nonsense operators, but why bother? The above messy expressions apparently do make sense in elasticity theory, but I suspect general relativity theory people do not find them invariant enough under general coordinate transformations.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, so the logarithm of a tensor is not a  tensor. I had missed that. Anyway, I saw this in General Relativity, people add terms to the action of the form $\int d^4 x\, \log \Box R$...

Comment: @RubenCamposDelgado But surely in that example $R$ is the Ricci scalar, rather than an abbreviation for the Ricci tensor $R_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I meant $\int d^4 x \, R_{\mu \nu}\log\Box R^{\mu \nu}$

Comment: @RubenCamposDelgado in that context it almost certainly means logarithm as an operator, since logarithms appear in Lagrangians when thinking of them in terms of eigenvalues of an operator, e.g. it is common in effective field theory to have the logarithm of the Laplacian.

Comment: @JamalS so if I had to take the variation of the action, wouldn't be correct to write $\delta S=\int d^4x (\delta R_{\mu \nu})\log \Box R^{\mu \nu}+R_{\mu \nu}\frac{1}{\Box R_{\mu \nu}}(\Box \delta R_{\mu \nu})$? After all, $\Box R_{\mu \nu}$ gives me a function and I take the logarithm of that function